# Applying the igraph assortativity function to specific node labels?

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph

I have several networks that I would like to use the assortativity function on. The problem is, I am only interested if nodes of one particular label tend to cluster together, and I don't want nodes of other labels to interfere. Is there a way to isolate the assortativity index so that it only takes the nodes with one label, rather than all labels?

Or, is it best if I use the numerical version and relabel my nodes of interest to "1", and all other node labels to "0"?

Here is a small example

```
links <- data.frame("From" = c(1, 1, 2,
                               2, 3, 9,
                               4, 5, 2),
                    "To" = c(3, 2, 1,
                             5, 9, 5,
                             1, 9, 1))
links

nodes <- data.frame("Food" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9),
                    "Type" = c("soup", "bread", "pickles",
                               "vegtables", "drink", "potato side")
                    )
nodes

nw <- graph_from_data_frame(d = links,
                            vertices = nodes,
                            directed = T)
assortativity.nominal(nw, 
                      V(nw)$Type,
                      directed = T)
```

How would I calculate the tendency of potato sides to be with each other?